# catching the assertion failure message before handling it

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I know how to raise an exception and how to handle it , but suppose I have this method:

```
method1:arg
AssertionFailure signal:'rescue error comment'.
```

I want to catch this exception and create new Assertion failure exception with another format.However I need to get that message ("rescue error comment") and use it in my new exception.. and this is where I don't know what to do...

so how do I get that message before the handling the exeption by using

```
   on: AssertionFailure  do:
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question. You have an error, and you can catch it with `#on:do:` why do you want to change it somewhere in a middle? Why don't you signal something different then _AssertionFailure_? Why don't you signal exactly what you want?

Comment: ya it might seem a bit weird.. but my new Assertion failure has a different format.. and I just need to find a way to save that signal message.. is there any way ?

Comment: Either you do `on: AssertionFailure do: [ :e | NewAssertionFailure signal: e messageText ]` or you do `NewAssertionFailure signal: e messageText` directly in `method1:arg`. If you can tell why these 2 options are bad, maybe I'll be able to figure out which solution would be good.

Comment: no this is perfect.. I have used on: AssertionFailure do: [ :e | NewAssertionFailure signal: e messageText ]  and it works.. this is what I wanted :-) you are the best

Comment: You are welcome, mover solution to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use

```
on: AssertionFailure do: [ :e | NewAssertionFailure signal: e messageText ]
```

or define method as

```
method1:arg
    NewAssertionFailure signal: 'rescue error comment'
```